# Category based list View in django

Tags: python, django

I have two model 1 is category, 2nd is details and I want make a view where i can click on a category and the link should take me to the list only for the current category what i clicked.
my models are given:

```
class FoodCategory(models.Model):
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categorydetails = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    categoryimage = models.ImageField(default='cat_def.jpg', 
    upload_to='catimg')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Food Category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryname


class FoodDetails(models.Model):
    fromcategory = models.ForeignKey(FoodCategory, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foodname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fooddetails = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    foodimage = models.ImageField(default='food_def.jpg', 
    upload_to='fodimg')
    armodel = models.CharField(default='andy.sfb', max_length=50)
    additiondate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    addedby = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Food Detail'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fromcategory.categoryname + \
           ' - ' + self.foodname + \
           ' - ' + 'added by' + \
           ' - ' + self.addedby.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('food-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from food.models import FoodCategory, FoodDetails
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView


class FoodCategoryView(ListView):
    model = FoodCategory
    template_name = 'food/food-category.html'
    context_object_name = 'food'


class FoodListView(ListView):
    model = FoodDetails
    template_name = 'food/food-list.html'
    context_object_name = 'food'

    ordering = ['-additiondate']


class FoodDetailsView(DetailView):
    model = FoodDetails
    template_name = 'food/FoodDetails_detail.html'
```

and my urls.py file also:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from .views import FoodCategoryView, FoodListView, FoodDetailsView

# api url handler

urlpatterns = [
    path('category/', FoodCategoryView.as_view(), name='food- 
    category'),
    path('foodlist/', FoodListView.as_view(), name='food-list'),
    path('foodlist/<int:pk>/', FoodDetailsView.as_view(), 
    name='food-details')

]
```

here is my all files and i just want know a specific way to get the current category based food details.

Comment: I think you have to read Django documentation in order to learn how you can create a view and return result in a django template : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/

Here you have just the model. It's not enough.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [Ask] so you know what kind of questions are appropriate on this forum. You need to show a specific problem you're facing, it's not the purpose of SO that others write code for you. Please write your view first, show that you've made an effort yourself by reading the documentation and tried it yourself. When facing a specific issue, you can ask about it here.

Comment: i will update the url and view too soon

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining `get_queryset` on a listview.

```
class FoodDetailsByCategory(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return FoodDetails.objects.filter(fromcategory_id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
```

with a simple URL:

```
path('category/<int:category_id>', FoodDetailsByCategory.as_view(), name='food_details_by_category')
```